# Visual Basic 2010: Iteration through properties with similar name?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, properties, iteration

I have created a simple application where I fetch questions from an Access database and store the answers to another Access database. I am not sure how many questions client would like to ask, so I can't hardcode that number.

So, column names for answers table (besides user information like first, last name and so on) will be a1, a2, a3 ... aN.

And finally the problem!

For testing purposes I have hardcoded saving first 3 answers like this:

```
newEntry.a1 = answers(0)
newEntry.a2 = answers(1)
newEntry.a3 = answers(2)
```

Now I would like to iterate through all properties based on count of "a-type" properties:

```
'aCount is number of "a-type" properties
For i = 0 To aCount - 1
    Dim property As String
    property = "a" & (i + 1)
    newEntry.property = answers(i)
Next
```

Of course, above code does not work, it is just a pseudo-code idea that "should" to the same as my hardcoded example.

Is it possible to iterate through predefined properties of newEntry object in that manner?

I hope my question was clear enough. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Don't let a badly broken dbase table design break your code as well.  Maybe you ought to fix the table first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is using reflection, you'd be better off using a collection to store your answers.

lots of ways you could do it, but

```
Dictionary<String,List<String>> would be an easy first choice then
```

PSEUDO Code

```
for(int index = 0; index<aCount; index++)
{
  newEntries.Add["A"].Add(answers[index]);
}
```

so A4 is simply newEntries["A"][3];